# Horizontal Navigation with Expanding SubNav

Tags: jquery, css, nav

So I've been poking around for a while and cannot find an answer to this.

What I'm looking to do is have a navigation of 4 or so main navigation topics. Clicking each topic will expand below a list of subnav items pertaining to that topic (ie, click 'Hardware' and all the hardware subtopics will be displayed).

The idea is similar to what you'll see clicking 'Shows' on thecomedynetwork.ca

I'm also hoping that when they click on the other main nav, the subnav will close and open to the new subnav (ie. 'Hardware' will close and 'Software' will open).

Sorry if I'm being extremely vague, and I'd post code but I'm literally scrapping everything I'm trying.

Update:
So JUST when I thought I'd nailed it, I can't get this thing to execute properly. The jsfiddle is showing it working how I need it (minus obvious polish like easing): http://jsfiddle.net/HGTKZ/1/

```
var divs = $('#nav div'),
links = $('a');

links.click(function () {
$(this.hash).toggle().siblings().hide();
return false;
});
```

But when published this thing just won't work:
http://agiile.com/testing6.html

I have the jquery linked (1.9.1 min from Google APIs) and I'm getting no syntax errors... but this seemingly simple code won't run!

As an aside, if anyone has a suggestion to improve my html and not use #software, #hardware etc that'd be awesome. javascript:void(0) would be preferable, but I can't think of how to make it work in this situation.

Thanks for the help along the way so far guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have searched Google before.

Anyways, search for "CSS Navigation" bars. You'll find plenty of examples. They'll do the trick.

Okay, then you can build up a menu like that

1. Hide it initially using CSS

   .menu{
      display: none;
   }
2. Setup event handlers to toggle + animate the submenu display.
3. Use Jquery for that slideDown Animation.

Comment: Definitely promise I'm doing a terrible job at finding what I need.

I think the biggest issue I'm having is getting the subnav to take full width below the nav bar.

Like, I can get a CSS nav bar, but it's the expansion of the full width subnav below that is catching me up.

Comment: @SpencerFord is this better?

Comment: You've definitely helped me find what I need to be researching. Thanks bud!

I'll report back when I find I'm more lost than I currently think!

Thanks Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. If you Google for 'Jquery dropdown' or 'Javascript dropdown' you will find something like this:

http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

That should help I guess ;)

Comment: Thanks for putting up with my sheer vagueness!

I've been able to get those to work before, I'm just looking to try something I haven't done before in having a full width dropdown that remains open.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the issue went with my update working in jsfiddle.net, Taking the code from jsfiddle.net/draft after running seems to have fixed that!

Not entirely sure where the code went awry there, but it's working now. Thanks guys!